# Magento 2 - PHP Vulnerabilities message

Tags: magento2, php, critical, vulnerability, notice

I am getting PHP Vulnerabilities notification and it is showing critical.

> Reminder on PHP Vulnerabilities
> MS-ISAC has issued an alert related to
>   multiple vulnerabilities that could allow for arbitrary code execution
>   and a recommendation that all sites using PHP should update to the
>   latest PHP version ASAP. Since Magento Commerce relies on PHP, we
>   recommend that all Merchants using Magento Commerce review necessary
>   updates for PHP with their hosting provider by September 30 in order
>   to mitigate the vulnerability. Magento Commerce customers using our
>   cloud infrastructure may redeploy at any time now to take advantage of
>   the latest patches (ahead of our previously stated start date of
>   September 19).

This link is set on read more: https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360033561271-Magento-Recommendations-for-PHP-Vulnerabilities

Can anyone help me apply this PHP patch please, what patch do I need to apply and how can I apply it?

**Magento Version: 2.2.5**
**OS: Ubuntu**
**PHP Version: 7.1.24**
**PHP-FPM is also used**
**Web server: nginx**